# Mod operator limits variables?

Tags: random, numbers

When using random numbers in any language people always do something like *random % 100 + 1* to limit whatever number from the range of *1* to *100*. But how does the mod operator limit it? I though it was just used for calculating remainders? Can someone explain this to me?

Answer (score 1):

`mod` is used for calculating remainders, that's true. And a remainder is always limited by (divisor-1). So the result of `random % 100` always belongs to `[0, 99]`.

Another useful property of `mod` is that it maps the initial range into the result range rather 'fairly'. That is, probability of `random mod N == k` tends to be 1/N with the growth of random's range, and is exactly 1/N if N is a divisor of random's range (for an evenly distributed `random` of course).